# Reading integer via serial port in arduino

Tags: c, arduino

i need help about my small project i have arduino and im reading integer values via serial port to control LED so im getting trouble if i insert any value via serial monitor LED turns on, i want to control LED according to conditions in the code.
i want to read integer value in the serial monitor and control the led according to a value received via serial port.

heres my  codes

```
   int All;  

int LEDpin =13;

Void Setup()

{

PinMode(LEDPin,OUTPUT);

}  

Void Loop()

{

       While( Serial,Available()==0)



  All=Serial.intParse();

if (All=1)


{

digitalWrite(LEDpin,HIGH);



}


if (All=0)


{


digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);
}

if  (All=2)

{

digitalWrite(LEDpin,HIGH);  
delay(1000);  
digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);  

}

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code and remove superfluous white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you set your variable `All` in your code instead of checking it against a value:

instead of:

```
if(All=1){
  ...
}
```

you should write:

```
if(All == 1){
  ...
}
```

**edit:**

And you should take a look at the naming convention:

- use `void` instead of `Void`
- name your member-variables with small letters `all` instead of `All`
- big letters at the beginning should be for classes in C++ or other OOP-languages

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of things to fix. First of all what @Tom Mekken pointed out you make comparisons with `==`, not `=`. Then you access members with `.` instead of `,`. And you should read until `available` is greater than zero, not equal to. And the `setup` and `loop` functions are NOT `Setup` and `Loop`, like `PinMode` and `While` and `Void` (C is case sensitive). And you should initialize the serial communication with the baud rate. And `LEDPin` is not `LEDpin`. And `intParse` is not `ParseInt`.

And... Indent it properly. Here is your code fixed:

```
int All;  

int LEDpin = 13;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);
}  

void loop()
{
    while( Serial.available() > 0)
        All = Serial.parseInt();
    if (All == 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(LEDpin,HIGH);
    }
    if (All == 0)
    {
        digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);
    }
    if (All == 2)
    {
        digitalWrite(LEDpin,HIGH);  
        delay(1000);  
        digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);  
    }
}
```

Now, that was just the core part. Your code, however, has also functional problems. Instead of a bunch of if I suggest you to use a switch. And instead of reading a whole integer, since your data is just single-digit, I suggest you to read just one char. This way you won't have problems with other chars and, moreover, you won't have problems when there are available non-printable chars.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
int LEDpin = 13;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);
}  

void loop()
{
    switch (Serial.read())
    {
        case '1':
            digitalWrite(LEDpin,HIGH);
            break;
        case '0':
            digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);
            break;
        case '2':
            digitalWrite(LEDpin,HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);
            break;
    }
}
```